# Run query in Rails, how to save results (csv) as column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, export-to-csv

I wrote Ruby code to run a query that connects to an API and outputs a repot. When I run it locally through Terminal it saves the results as a CSV file. I'd like to configure my Rails app to do the same, either saving the output as a column or creating a file download. What's the best way to go about doing this? Since there isn't a column type for file, should I do a string using CSV?

Currently I'm doing the following to create the CSV:

```
CSV.open("LOCATION/FILENAME") do |csv|
FIELDS
csv << [FIELD NAMES]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about this for quite some time, and then realized that I should save the CSV data as an array of hashes. In the migration I used `t.json :array_of_hashes, default: []` for the table, since array isn't a valid field type. 
Next, I'll use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2634185/1774593) suggestion to render the array as a table on the Show view page, and J.P.'s suggestion to render the table as a CSV to download.

Answer (score 0):

You can respond to requests for your CSV in your controller by creating your own "renderer", where your typical requests respond with HTML or JSON, you can also have your controllers respond to requests with a PDF or like your case a CSV, here's some reasonable documentation on that: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Renderers.html.

In short, you can do something like this (from the docs):

Create a csv renderer:

```
ActionController::Renderers.add :csv do |obj, options|
  filename = options[:filename] || 'data'
  str = obj.respond_to?(:to_csv) ? obj.to_csv : obj.to_s
  send_data str, type: Mime[:csv],
    disposition: "attachment; filename=#{filename}.csv"
end
```

Note that we used Mime for the csv mime type as it comes with Rails. For a custom renderer, you'll need to register a mime type with `Mime::Type.register`.

To use the csv renderer in a controller action:

```
def show
  @csvable = Csvable.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { render csv: @csvable, filename: @csvable.name }
  end
end
```

Comment: @SkunkDog, did my answer help you? If so could you mark it as correct? :)

Comment: I haven't had the opportunity to test this yet, I'll confirm this afternoon.

Comment: Sorry, it took me awhile to wrap my head around this. I think what you describe will allow me to basically download the Show page as a CSV, right? However, I am running an API call that generates a large table of data. I want the results of this call to be downloadable as a CSV. Since there are a lot of entries in each table (like 1000+) I don't want to save each entry as its own database item. How can I allow that table to be downloaded?